# colMeans command returning NA

Tags: r

I am using colMeans for a panel data set. In particular, I have chosen population growth and wish to take the average for every row like such:

```
n1=colMeans(matrix(Growth$pg, nrow=28))
```

Even though there is no data missing in the data set my output looks like this:

```
    [1]  1.332363052  0.456903492  0.481547234  1.044043748  1.207003186  0.062924111  0.379555304  0.381756287  0.524334772
[10]  0.111754049  0.306285644 -0.241963019  1.033342262  1.095561659  2.391910159  0.280539029  0.132923826  1.555325866
[19]  0.509258732           NA  0.780181250  0.005286703  0.155291793  0.719622122  0.529946873  0.834386164  0.496087741
[28]  1.020665658
```

Is there a way to make it such that it takes the average of each row and if there is a value missing, it disregards it by still taking the average of the whole roW?

Thanks

Comment: add `na.rm = TRUE`

Comment: Doesn't work i'm afraid, i tried this and it gives the output that i will enclose at the end of the question

Comment: my apologies, I see now that you add na.rm=TRUE, outside the bracket and has worked. thanks

Comment: `na.rm` is an argument of `colMeans`, so it goes in there